# A classfile is not created

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I use emacs to write java and compile and run through terminal on Mac.
I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx
    at Testprogram2.<init>(Task.java:86)
    at Task.main(Task.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 2 more
```

I even changed name of xxx class, but it still won´t create this class. There are about other 20 classes that are created, but not this class. How to solve this?

EDIT:

The class is defined this way (nothing special):

```
class xxx extends superXXX{

     xxx(String number, double price){
          super(number,price);
     }

     //other methods here

}

class superXXX implements onlyXXX{

    String number;
    double price;
    double result;

    superXXX(String number, double price){
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
        double p = calculatePrice();
        result = p;
    }

   //other methods here

}
```

I write first "java Task.java", then I get this error message after having written "javac Task" on Terminal and when it encounters the line that creates an object of xxx:

```
xxx pb1 = new xxx("Reg1", 5000.0);
```

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough context to diagnose this. It could be a classpath error, a compilation error... any number of things.

Comment: @Jon which information should you need to know?

Comment: How you're compiling, how you're running, anything more about the class (is it nested, anything unusual etc).

Comment: Some code from around `Testprogram2.<init>(Task.java:86)` would be helpful, how is `xxx` defined, how are you calling the `javac` compiler?

Comment: Its all in **one** `.java` file, called `Task.java`?

Comment: @andreas that is right. Why ALL other class files are created, but not this class. There are other classes that extends superXXX.

Comment: Split superXXX out into its own java source file - it will be easier to manage and debug that way at the very least.  Also, which class definition actually contains the main method?

Comment: @stick Ok. the main method is called "public static void main(String [] args){}" Before I implemented this class xxx, the programs was running fine.

Comment: To be more specific, the question is which *class* definition *contains* the main method?

Comment: @Stick In class Task.

Comment: Try making xxx a public class.

Comment: @stick I splitted xxx and superXXX into two separate java-files, but I still get same error message. I have compiled these two files beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've already done this (from reading the example above), but I'd also split your code into separate files for each class and interface.

You also need to make sure the classes are public, and so usable by classes from other packages as necessary. (Obviously make sure methods and members are private or protected if necessary!)

(EDIT: Also someone else rightly answered earlier that you need to have "class" before

```
superXXX implements onlyXXX{...
```

so it should be

```
class superXXX implements onlyXXX{...
```

but for some reason that answer no longer exists...)

Comment: It was a typo, of course I have "class" in front of "superXXX".